# Both control key doesnt work

Tags: keyboard

Both my control keys don't work. I can neither use them to select multiple files nor use Ctrl+Alt+Del. The basic Ctrl button doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Could be an application problem or a hardware problem.

To rule out sofware, try using Ctrl with the onscreen keyboard

```
Start, "osk"
```

Do you have another keyboard installed?

Do you have any accessibility settings enabled? (Ease of Access centre in control pannel)